# Where is the file that operate <?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?> form action in Magento product view page

Tags: forms, magento, action

I see there is the following code in the app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml file:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

Is there a file that operate this action `action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>"`?

What file?

Comment: Upvoting to offset the unnecessary downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In magento each '.phtml' file is associated with a block file which contain the available template method.

The block for template\catalog\product\view.phtml template is located in

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php
>
> class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract

However getSubmitUrl($_product) is inherit from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`

> /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php

```
public function getSubmitUrl($product, $additional = array())
{
    ...
}
```

Read more @ [Intro to Layouts](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference R.S.